# Splitting table data to pages with numbers

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to split table data from a database to different pages, everything is good until now, but when I try to to add (?page=) at the end of the url it doesn't work, it's a wordpress page so the url is (www.example.com/page) , when I add for example (?page=) at the end of the url it transfers me to (www.example.com/page/2) but the data are still the same, I limited it to show 4 records in 1 page.

Here's the code to fetch the data from the db, displaying them in a table and limiting them :

```
            <?php
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "players";


                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

                $start = intval($_GET['start']);
                $limit = 4;

                $sql = "SELECT name, id, connections, first_seen, last_seen FROM players ORDER BY id LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["connections"]."</td><td>".$row["first_seen"]."</td><td>".$row["last_seen"]."</td></tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                } 

                else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }
                $conn->close();
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use another variable name?
For example: ?pagenum=....

And then on your code you would read that variable:

```
$start = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? intval( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
```

Comment: Did this helped?